# easy statement:what's the error in my SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I can't find the syntax error.
The `spirit` table is as belows:
[image]

```
mysql> UPDATE spirit SET defend = 20, hp = 110, interval = 4 WHERE spirit_ID = 4;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval = 4 WHERE spirit_ID = 4' at line 1
```

I am so confused, thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: `interval` is a reserved word. Enclose it inside backticks or better change its name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping `interval` with backticks(**``**):

```
UPDATE spirit SET defend = 20, hp = 110, `interval` = 4 WHERE spirit_ID = 4;
```